# What is the best eBay sniping software or service out there?

Tags: windows, gratis, android, ios, ebay

I’m looking for [auction sniping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auction_sniping) software and or service to snipe action on eBay.

- Free!
- Cross platform client such as Android, iOS and even Windows).

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: I made the question on-topic.

Comment: Yes you did. Though I wonder where from you extracted the additional details – or whether they're just a good guess :)

Comment: For the record, eBay changed their system to make sniping essentially pointless several years ago. Instead of just making a bid, you submit/commit the most that you are willing to pay, then it accepts the lowest amount for you to win. If someone makes a bid, it automatically raises your bid to match up to your maximum. Therefore, sniping doesn’t work if someone else has a higher maximum bid than you, and in fact, it would blow the auction for you to wait until the last second because you won’t have enough time to see their auto-bid outbid your snipe and react. (Yet lots of people still do it.)

Comment: @Synetech I believe proxy bidding was there from day one.

Comment: Proxy bidding is not sniping; they changed the way bidding works to render sniping moot. Your question is specifically about “sniping”, not generic proxy-bidding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your tags it seems like you are looking into something with iOS and Android support.

I use [Myibidder](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myibidder-auction-bid-sniper/id595892978) for my own sniping purposes. It's available for iOS (offers both iPad and iPhone support) and Android as well.
I like it because it allows me to browse eBay and import my Watch List, and also supports groups (where you set a number of snipes, then the sniping stops after you win a certain amount of items).

The reviews look good for both iOS and Android. There are some users who are not happy, but developers looks active on that by properly suggesting good ways on resolving it.

Whenever you have an issue or just a simple question their support is fast when you try to contact them.

**Update regarding reliability:**

I used Myibidder for quite some time. Not sure when I started but I pushed several hundreds of snipes for sure.

During this time I got a few failures only. One failure was because eBay reset my password for some weird reasons. Another failure was because of network time-out (I think eBay was having some performance issues a few years ago. Never saw it again). One more failure was when eBay made some huge changes on their website, Myibidder reacted quickly but I was lucky enough to have my snipe right in between.

**Update regarding the pricing:**

I see they have two Android versions right now: free and paid. The paid version has some additional perks which I don't use.

They also have two iOS versions: PPS and non-PPS. Their description said PPS is Pay Per Snipe. It seems like the non-PPS version offers unlimited sniping.
I personally use PPS version because it comes cheaper overall. They charge for won snipes only, and their fees are the lowest I could find. You could always replenish snipes using in-app purchase. I see no problems paying for a great service, I save money on sniping after all.

And here is the bonus: Myibidder has the [Web version of the sniper](http://www.myibidder.com/) which is free. They said this version will always be free.
I used to use Web version on my iPad before I switched to the native app.

Comment: As the requirements list "free", "very fast", and "reliable": how does *Myibidder* match these? (I'm aware these details were added with a later edit, so I'm not blaming you for omission – but could you please update your answer nevertheless? ;)

Comment: @nochkin Thank you for your answer. I've tried few and this one is better one (if not the best) out there today by far! I saved myself thousands of dollars over period of time)